# Detect when a "remove" coupon button is clicked in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

How can I detect that **Remove** button/link clicked to remove the coupon from the checkout page in woocommerce.

[image: please check the image for reference]

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to live detect when "remove coupon" is clicked this way:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'coupon_removed_script' );
function coupon_removed_script() {
    if( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ):
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $('a.woocommerce-remove-coupon').on( 'click', function(){
                console.log('click remove coupon');
                alert('click remove coupon');
            });
        })
        </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

And you can also use the following code to do something when coupon is removed *(where* `$coupon_code` *is the removed coupon code argument)*:

```
add_action("woocommerce_removed_coupon", 'coupon_removed_action');
function coupon_removed_action( $coupon_code ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: thanks for your reply but the code is not working for me.

Comment: @Sushil You should give me a live link and a coupon code to see, as your theme seems to be custom… If not you need to replace `'a.woocommerce-remove-coupon'` by the right tag class related to that button, to make the code work.

Comment: [Bagdara Farms](https://bagdarafarms.com/demo-site-test/shop) and the code is `tester`

Comment: @Sushil I have visit your web site and `'a.woocommerce-remove-coupon'` is just fine, **but it doesn't work because there is multiple javascript errors actually on checkout page** *(and also in cart page)*…